# CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD Apex Error - Update

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-flow

I've created a scheduled flow that triggers on the following conditions:

1. Lead has a related account via a Lookup
2. Lead Has_Activity__c = True
3. Lead IsConverted = False

When this is scheduled to trigger it will call upon my Apex Class to convert the leads however I am running into Flow Errors saying that *"n Apex error occurred: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD* However the lead was not converted

How can I update my Apex Code so that it wont return this error? I tried to attempt this by creating batch based on what ChatGPT told me to do :) But I think I need one of you experts to help me out :)

```
public with sharing class ConvertLeads {

    public class LeadConvertRequest {

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Lead ID'
            description = 'ID of the Lead to convert'
            required = true
        )
        public ID leadId;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Account ID'
            description = 'The specific Account to convert Lead into. If blank then creates new Account.'
        )
        public ID accountId;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Contact ID'
            description = 'The specific Contact to convert Lead into. If blank then creates new Contact.'
        )
        public ID contactId;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Create Opportunity?'
            description = 'Create an Opportunity? Default is true.'
        )
        public Boolean createOpportunity = false;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Owner ID'
            description = 'Specific user to own the new Account, Contact, and Opportunity records created. Default is the Lead owner.'
        )
        public ID ownerId;

    }

    public class LeadConvertResult {

        @InvocableVariable( label = 'Lead ID' )
        public ID leadId;

        @InvocableVariable( label = 'Account ID' )
        public ID accountId;

        @InvocableVariable( label = 'Contact ID' )
        public ID contactId;

        @InvocableVariable( label = 'Opportunity ID' )
        public ID opportunityId;

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Convert Leads'
    )
    public static void convertLeads( List<LeadConvertRequest> requests ) {
        
    LeadStatus ConvertedStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];    
    List<Database.LeadConvert> convertRequests = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(LeadConvertRequest request : requests) {
        Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvert.setLeadId(request.leadId);
        if(request.accountId?.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setAccountId(request.accountId);
        }
        if(request.contactId?.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setContactId(request.contactId);
        }
        leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(request.createOpportunity == false);
        if(request.ownerId?.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setOwnerId(request.ownerId);
        }
        convertRequests.add(leadConvert);
        }
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> convertResults = Database.convertLead(convertRequests, true);

        Database.convertLead(convertRequests, true);
    }
    


        private static Database.LeadConvert transform( LeadConvertRequest request, String convertedStatus ) {

        Database.LeadConvert convertRequest = new Database.LeadConvert();

        convertRequest.setLeadId( request.leadId );
        convertRequest.setConvertedStatus( convertedStatus  ); // Use the variable retrieved from the query

        if ( request.accountId != null ) {
            convertRequest.setAccountId( request.accountId );
        }

        if ( request.contactId != null ) {
            convertRequest.setContactId( request.contactId );
        }

        if ( request.createOpportunity != null && !request.createOpportunity ) {
            convertRequest.setDoNotCreateOpportunity( !request.createOpportunity );
        }

        if ( request.ownerId != null ) {
            convertRequest.setOwnerId( request.ownerId );
        }

        return convertRequest;
    }


    public class ConvertLeadException extends Exception {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to query the lead records to convert them, as you already have the Lead Id, and you have all the other details already (they're in `LeadConvertRequest`). Also, you can't query in a loop if you want to avoid limits, so move the query to get the converted status to the `convertLeads` method. Finally, don't use 500 for the batch size. Triggers are in batches of 200, so using 500 would split, for example, a list of 1000 items into 6 transactions instead of 5.

Your code can be as simple as:

```
public static void convertLeads(List<LeadConvertRequest> requests) {
        LeadStatus ConvertedStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> convertRequests = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(LeadConvertRequest request : requests) {
        Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvert.setLeadId(request.leadId);
        leadConvert.setConvertedStatus(ConvertedStatus.MasterLabel);
        if(request.accountId?.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setAccountId(request.accountId);
        }
        if(request.contactId?.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setContactId(request.contactId);
        }
        leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(request.createOpportunity == false);
        if(request.ownerId?.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType) {
            leadConvert.setOwnerId(request.ownerId);
        }
        convertRequests.add(leadConvert);
    }
    Database.convertLead(batch, true);
}
```

Note: you shouldn't use global unless you plan on making this an ISV managed package to install in subscriber orgs. `public` is just fine for most use cases.

Comment: Man I am really screwing this up where you have Database.convertLead(batch, true) 

Do I replace batch with Database.convertLead(convertRequests, true);

Comment: I just edited the original submission to what I currently have @sfdcfox 

I removed batch with ConvertRequests since it was saying "Variable does not exist: batch"

and at least for now im not getting any errors

Comment: Ah but when I run the flow I get this error 

An Apex error occurred: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: @andrew Yes, there was a typo in the code. `contactId.getSobjectType()` should have been `contactId?.getSobjectType()`. I've edited that in.

Comment: Do you know why I would be getting there Apex Error when running my flow :( 

An Apex error occurred: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, convertedStatus is required.: [Status]

Comment: Do you by any chance offer tutoring or freelance work? Apologies if thats not allowed to be asked in this forum

Comment: @andrew I forgot to copy-paste the status field. I've edited the code in the answer. This latest version should work fine. You can contact me by email, but my time is limited, so I can't promise anything.

Comment: No worries sfdcfox I am always so appreciate of you! I was trying my hardest not to bug you

Comment: @andrew Thanks!